# Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{x+iy}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

> I would like to calculate Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{x+iy}$ in $\mathcal{S}' (\mathbb{R}^2)$.

I did it as follows: $$\widehat{x+iy}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-({ix\xi_1+y\xi_2})}\frac{1}{x+iy}dx\, dy\,=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-({ix\xi_1+y\xi_2})}\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}dx\, dy\,$$ $$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-{ix\xi_1}}\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dx\,-i\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-{y\xi_2}}\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}dy\,$$

Now it reduces to find the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{x^2+y2}$ which will give us the Fourier transform of $x\cdot \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$. But I'm unable to calculate the FT of $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ has a non-integrable singularity at $0$, and since it is positive, you can't even take a principal value to get an element of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: So what can be the alternative to this?

Comment: What's your definition of Fourier transform?

Answer (score 0):

Set $T=\frac{1}{z}$ as tempered distribution, then since $z$ is tempered distribution, $zT\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$, take fourier transform to $zT$, we have $$
\widehat{zT}=\widehat{xT}+i\widehat{yT}=\frac{1}{-2\pi i}\bar{\partial}\hat{T}=\hat{1}=\delta$$,
where $\bar\partial=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$,then you need to show $\frac{1}{2\pi z}$ is a fundamental solution to $\bar\partial$. (hint: polar coordinates ). Then we have $\hat{T}=\frac{-i}{z}$